# Mapping key in "Follow Hint" mode in Vimperator

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, vimperator

I am wanting to add a key map for using when follow hints mode is active, but cannot seem to find any way to add a keybinding for this mode.

I would like to add a <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to be mapped to <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> while hints are displayed.

I appreciate any tips you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pentadactyl doesn't have those bindings for hints mode by default. Or did you mean you could remap them in Pentadactyl?

For the record, if anyone wants to change these bindings in hints mode in Pentadactyl, you can do so by adding the following commands to your `.pentadactylrc` file:

```
:map -modes hints -b <C-n> <Tab>
:map -modes hints -b <C-p> <S-Tab>
```

Vimperator doesn't offer the ability to remap keys in hints mode, although you could probably do it with Javascript if you look into the source

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a solution, but the Pentadactyl fork works correctly and can be configured properly.